# Функции встроенной в Windows 7 OpenGL ограниченны

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-7

Я пытаюсь изучить OpenGL. Возник вопрос по её установке. Как я узнал, в Windows 7 есть встроенная библиотека OpenGL. Нашел у себя в папке `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl` два файла; `GL.h` и `GLU.h`. Создал консольный проект Visual C++, подключил их туда, инициализировал окно с помощью GLUT. Нарисовал куб, поигрался с формами, разукрасил.

Всё работает. Дальше хочу попробовать поработать с шейдерами. **И тут вопрос:** Почему в этой встроенной OpenGL нет функций по работе с шейдерами? Где мне их найти? При проверке версии с помощью `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` возвращает: «OpenGL version:4.5.0 NVIDIA 355.82».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой GLEW, для получения доступа к функциям для работы с шейдерами.

Comment: Смотрите мой коммент на второй ответ) Но, ваш ответ самый точный и верный.

Comment: @cvvvlad рекомендую почитать мою заметку на эту тему: http://mstislavpavlov.blogspot.ru/2016/01/opengl.html

Answer (score 4):

1. OpenGL — не встроенная библиотека, а спецификация.
2. Библиотеки под конкретную платформу, как правило, предоставляет производитель видеокарт (в вашем случае NVIDIA)
3. Заголовочные файлы можно либо скачать с http://www.opengl.org/registry, либо установить *Windows Software Development Kits* или, если вы используете VS, поставить соответствующий флажок при установке студии.
4. Заголовочный файл для `glCreateShader` — `glext.h`.
5. Проще всего использовать что-нибудь типа Qt, где это все уже реализовано.

Comment: Спасибо, я имел ввиду что у меня стоит Windows Kits. В итоге я поставил GLEW и он всё сделал за меня(нет надобности самому запрашивать адреса функций из glext.h). Qt есть, но хотел бы разобраться конкретно с OpenGL без всяких фишек Qt, а потом уже возможно его использовать. Читаю "Супрекнигу OpenGL". Всё получается =)